# Error - groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: gitUser for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I write pipeline in jenkinsfile. My groovy script work in script console, but in jenkinsfile I got error. I don't understand what is wrong.

```
[$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
      choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
      description: 'Select the BRANCH from the Dropdown List', 
      filterLength: 1, 
      filterable: false, 
      name: 'BRANCH',
      script: [$class: 'GroovyScript', 
        fallbackScript: [
            classpath: [], 
            sandbox: false, 
            script: 
                "return['Could not get The environemnts']"
        ],
        script: [
            classpath: [], 
            sandbox: false, 
            script: """ 
              import jenkins.*
              import jenkins.model.* 
              import hudson.*
              import hudson.model.*
                
                def jenkinsCredentials = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials( com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class, Jenkins.instance, null, null )
                    
                    for (creds in jenkinsCredentials) {
                    if(creds.id == "gitJenkins") {
                        gitUser = creds.username
                        gitPass = creds.password
                         }
                    }

                def proc = "git ls-remote -h https://${gitUser}:${gitPass}@gitlab.innochain.ru/innochain/backoffice.git".execute()
                return proc.text.readLines().collect {it.split()[1].replaceAll('refs/heads/', '')}

            """
        ]
      ]
    ]
 ])
])
```

It gives error. In scrip console script is working without error

```
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 4f0d1584-9bcb-45cf-8f49-f16c82dd9511
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: gitUser for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:285)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:375)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:379)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:35)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:73)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
```

I try declare gitUser and gitPass.
I try change syntax to "$(gitUser)"